# Proof of Diagonal MASA in Cuntz Algebra

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

First let me define some notations.

For $n \geq 2$, the Cuntz Algebra $\mathcal{O}_n$ is the $C^*$-algebra generated by $n$ isometries $S_1, \dots, S_n$ satisfying $\sum_{i=1}^n S_iS_i^* = \textrm{id}$. Up to isomorphism, $\mathcal{O}_n$ does not depend on the choice of isometries. Denote $W_n$ to be the set of finite tuples $\mu = (\mu_1, \dots, \mu_k)$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $\mu_m \in \{1, \dots, n\}$. Further, set $S_\mu = S_{\mu_1} \dots S_{\mu_k}$. Then define $\mathcal{D}_n$ to be the abelian $C^*$-subalgebra of $\mathcal{O}_n$ generated by the projections $S_\mu{S_\mu}^*$ for $\mu \in W_n$.

Now, in the literature it seems to be well-known that $\mathcal{D}_n$ is a MASA (maximum abelian subalgebra) of $\mathcal{O}_n$ and is referred to as the diagonal MASA. However, I could not find a proof for it. Even in the original paper by Cuntz and Krieger it is only mentioned that it is a MASA in a remark without proof. Could someone please point me to a reference which proves this or perhaps provide a proof?

Thank you.

Comment: "satisfying $\sum_{i=1}^n S_iS_i^*$'" is not a finished sentence.

Comment: If you consider the C*-algebra generated by things of the form $s_\mu s_\nu^*$ with potentially different words (of the same length), you get the CAR algebra. Then this C*-algebra you describe is a MASA in this copy of $M_{2^{\infty}}$. Does this help at all?

Comment: In the above comment, replace the CAR algebra with the UHF $M_{n^{\infty}}$ if $n \neq 2$. You still have a MASA in $M_{n^{\infty}}$.

Comment: @PStheman Thank you for your comments. Unfortunately, I am not very familiar in this topic. Could you please provide a reference for a proof that $\mathcal{D}_n$ is a MASA in the CAR algebra you described? Also, could you briefly explain (or give a reference) for how this implies that $\mathcal{D}_n$ is also a MASA in $\mathcal{O}_n$?

Comment: Not actually sure if it'll help! Just a first glance suggestion. I might have thought the fact that $\mathcal{O}_n$ has a conditional expectation onto $M_{n^{\infty}}$ and the fact that $\mathcal{D}_n$ was a MASA in $M_{n^{\infty}}$ might help. I'm not so sure anymore.